# Stop clicking link twice on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, hyperlink, mouseover

I have a link with a mouseover.

It works great in the browsers, but when I touch the link once on an ipad or iphone, only the mouseover changes.  I have to click twice for the link to work.

How do i make the link work with one touch?

Here is the link:

```
<div id="search">
   <a href="search.php" class="mag"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you handling the mouseover effect with JavaScript or CSS (with a selector like `a:hover`)

Comment: I'm using css to make the hover work.

Comment: hmmm, I've just become aware how many flavors of this issue there are...any chance you can throw up a quick codepen?  I did a test with the `:hover` on the parent instead of the a (`#search:hover a {}`) and it does behave differently, but both versions actually do initiate the navigation to the href on my iPad (iOS 8.3) without a second click:  http://pixelsonpurpose.com/touchHoverTest.html

Comment: Another thought: you could put the hover style in a media query targeting only larger screens, etc:

`@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {/*styles here*/ }`

that way there wouldn't be a hover behavior on a smaller screen size, but of course a small browser window on desktop would end up not having the hover behavior, either.  Seems there are a wide range of javascript plugins to do this, as well...seems a little bit heavy, but depends on how much you feel it improves the experience, I suppose.